# Get the first content of td via tr data-id

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have the following HTML code:

```
<tr data-id='23'>
   <td><a href='../index.php?typeID=23'>Title</a></td>
   <td><a href='updateArticleType.php?typeID=23'>Update</a></td>
   <td><a href='#' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal' class='warning-dialog' data-id='23'>Delete</a></td>
</tr>
```

And the following JQuery code:

```
$(function () {
    var lastClickId;
    $('.warning-dialog').click(function () {
        lastClickId = $(this).data("id");
        var str = $("tr[data-id='" + lastClickId + "']:first").text();
        alert(str);
    });
```

I need to get the `name` between the archos tags.

I tried the code above, but in the alert is get `"Name Update Delete"`.

My question is why it doesn't work and how can I fix it?

Comment: `tr` selects tr, not td

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking for the first `tr` instead of the first `td`.

Your selector wants to be more like this:

```
 $("tr[data-id='" + lastClickId + "']>td:first")
```

I don't recommend depending on the order of the `td`s for in your selector. One day, you may decide to add a new column to before the title column. That's the day your code breaks.

Consider a class name on the title and using it in your selector like so:

```
<tr class="data-item" data-id='23'>
   ...
   <td class="item-title">...</td>
   ...
</tr>
```

JS:

```
 $(".data-item[data-id='" + id + "'].item-title:first")
```

Answer (score 1):

You are targeting the `TR` not the First `TD's` `A` inside of that `TR`, Try this,

```
$("tr[data-id='" + lastClickId + "'] td:first a").text()
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sdxaV/1/)

Comment: @Rahaorabhu This is the same as my answer, except that you're also targeting the anchor. The anchor doesn't need to be targeted and just adds an additional restriction, making the markup more risky to change in the future.

Comment: @flem Yes there is no point in selecting the child in OP's context. So that I just removed it. and I just thought that targeting the required element is a good practice while trying to get its text. By the way you had provided some alternate methods using class. that's also nice. :)

Comment: Agree. I'm not keen on selecting by element. I avoid it at all costs, meaning my CSS, JS, markup are not dependent with the exception of a logical class structure. With such pattern, I'm able to change a table structure to a div structure, add/remove/rearrange elements with no affect to the JS and general CSS.